# Exception ignored in Tornado WebSocket on_message method

Tags: python, tornado

I have the following class:

```
class SessionHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

@tornado.gen.coroutine       
def on_message(self):
          yield self.application.c.check("xxx@gmail.com")
```

The check() function is something like

```
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def check(self,id):

      if id not in self.AUTH_METHOD.keys():
         raise InvalidXX
```

`InvalidXX` is a user defined exception that inherits from `Exception` class.

When this exception is raised nothing is displayed to the tornado console. However when I add try/except clauses around them the exception is picked up. I don't understand why this exception isn't being propagated to the console. Other exceptions E.g. Duplicate key in MongoDB are propagated and shown to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer applies to Tornado 4.4 and older. As of Tornado 4.5 `on_message` may be a coroutine and the code in the original question will work]

Coroutines are called differently from regular functions (i.e. they must be called with `yield`). Therefore, when you are defining a method to be called by the framework, you should only use a coroutine when the docs say something like "this method may be a coroutine". `WebSocketHandler.on_message` may not be a coroutine (as of Tornado 4.3).

Instead, you can use `IOLoop.spawn_callback` to start an independent coroutine from your `on_message` callback.

```
def on_message(self, msg):
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(process_message, msg)

@gen.coroutine
def process_message(self, msg):
    ...
```

An important distinction here is that `spawn_callback` detaches the coroutine from the code in `WebSocketHandler` that receives messages: you may get a second `on_message` call before the callback spawned in the first one has finished. Use the methods in the `tornado.locks` and `tornado.queues` modules to manage this concurrency. (By contrast, in `RequestHandler.data_received`, which *may* be a coroutine, you won't get a second chunk of data until the second has been processed, and an uncaught exception will abort the connection)

Comment: Ahh you just turned my sunday night coding session on its head :S lol. Was on_message() available as a co-routine prior to Tornado 4.3? Just curious why was this changed? I'm going to have to start getting a hand on the new spawn and queue functionality I guess...

Comment: No, `on_message` has never been allowed to be a coroutine. My mention of version 4.3 is in case it changes in the future and someone finds this answer.

Comment: No worries thanks Ben. I think I've had enough for one night ;) good night.

Comment: you sir, made my day! Thanks alot again!